# Change only one route param

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router

Let's say I have a `Route` with three params, like so:

```
<Route path="inbox/:filter/:middleFilter/:endFilter" component={Inbox}/>
```

**Is there any way for me to just update one of those params at a time?** For example, if the current URL is:

```
/inbox/asdf/1234/qwer
```

and I want to change the numbers `1234` (`middleFilter`), is there any React Router way of updating it? Something along the lines of:

```
history.push({
  params: {
    middleFilter: 6789
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I can think of is to read this.props.params, see what the current params are, rebuild the URL and push:

```
const { filter, endFilter } = this.props.params;
const middleFilter = 6789;

history.push(`/inbox/${filter}/${middleFilter}/${endFilter}`)
```

I'm not too keen on this solution though because I need to know what the URL looks like and all the available filters, but it works.